# How to programmatically check view permission to a url in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, moss

I am displaying a list of popular public bookmarks to the logged-in user. Some users dont have access to  these bookmark-urls and I want to suppress the results so that only accessible urls are shown to the user.

I tried to use the [DoesUserHavePermissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms441848.aspx) method, but the problem is that I am not sure what object does the url points to (item/list/web/site).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out :| 
when getting popular bookmarks from SocialTagManager i need to pass the logged-in users context i.e. SPServiceContext.Current and SharePoint will take care of the rest.